# How start the line graph after some space from intersection in recharts

Tags: plotly, recharts, linegraph

[image]

In the given image I want to implement the line graph in such a way that the line graph starting point (Jan) should start after some space (custom space).

This is the current implementation:

```
 <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={403}>
            <LineChart
              data={graphData}
              margin={{
                top: 67,
                right: 30,
                left: 4,
                bottom: 0,
              }}
              barCategoryGap="26%"
            >
              <CartesianGrid
                strokeDasharray="10"
                stroke="#E8E8E8"
                strokeWidth={"1px"}
              />
              <XAxis
                style={{
                  fontSize: selectedType === "Monthly" ? "12px" : "14px",
                  fontFamily: "Inter",
                  color: "#111827",
                }}
                dataKey="name"
                axisLine={{ stroke: "#E8E8E8" }}
                tickLine={{ stroke: "#FFFF" }}
                domain={["dataMin+20", "dataMax+20"]}
                interval={0}
              />
              <YAxis
                style={{
                  fontSize: selectedType === "Monthly" ? "12px" : "14px",
                  fontFamily: "Inter",
                  color: "#111827",
                }}
                dx={-15}
                axisLine={{ stroke: "#E8E8E8" }}
                tickLine={{ stroke: "#E8E8E8" }}
                tickFormatter={(tick) => `${tick}k`}
              />
              <Line
                type="monotone"
                dataKey="revenue"
                stroke="#417898"
                activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
                fill="#417898"
              />
            </LineChart>
          </ResponsiveContainer>
```

I have tried by adding domain property but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding to add custom space

```
  <XAxis dataKey="name" padding={{ left: 40 }}></XAxis>
```

This is how it looks

[image]